# Appendchild only works on last element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an element in JavaScript and apply it to all elements by class name. For this example I will use a paragraph for ease. The purpose of creating an element by JavaScript however is because I want to create a different element later on in my code.

In the code I am using, only the last element of the array of elements will contain the element created by the JavaScript. Could anyone explain why this is happening and what I could do to solve the problem accordingly to my requirement? I am trying to apply a whole element inside another element (so not just a value or property of a paragraph element).

My code:

```js
//Creating my element:
let myElement = document.createElement("p");
/*let text = document.createTextNode("test");
myElement.appendChild(text);*/ //<-- Enable following to see text in result or check developer console for added paragraphs

//Single example:
let ele = document.getElementById("bar");
ele.appendChild(myElement);

//Not working...:

//Now class:
let eles = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
  //eles[i].innerHTML = "abc";//<-- Does work (but hardcoded)?
  //eles[i].innerHTML = myElement;//<-- returns "[object HTMLParagraphElement]"?
  eles[i].appendChild(myElement); //<!-- Does work only for last element in array?
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar">

</div>
<div class="foo">

</div>

<div class="foo">

</div>

<div class="foo">
  <!-- Only this one will obtain the the paragraph element? -->
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cw3q2a7u/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `cloneNode` of element `<p>`, because `appendChild` moves it from its current position to the new position. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
//Creating my element:
const myElement = document.createElement("p");
myElement.innerHTML = 'paragraph';

//Single example:
const ele = document.getElementById("bar");
ele.appendChild(myElement.cloneNode(true));

//Now class:
const eles = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
  eles[i].appendChild(myElement.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
.foo {
   border: 1px solid #333;
}

.foo p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar">
  bar:
</div>
<div class="foo">
  foo1
</div>
<div class="foo">
  foo2
</div>
<div class="foo">
  foo3
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `<p>` element is appended only to the last because it is assigned to the `myElement`variable. And because that variable is declared before your loop, each iteration will move the `<p>` tag through all your `<div.foo>`.

But if you declare your paragraph **inside** your `for` loop, a new one is created and appended to each of your blocks, because there are all different elements.

```js
let eles = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
  let myElement = document.createElement("p");
  myElement.innerText = 'I am a paragraph.';

  eles[i].appendChild(myElement);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar">

</div>
<div class="foo">

</div>

<div class="foo">

</div>

<div class="foo">
  
</div>
```